# Output field question

Tags: visualforce

I am working on the Account VisualForce page, and on that page I have a custom field that is from a different object. I am able to display that field from the different object but right now it is in a table. Is there a way to output the field value without a table, but just a single line of text given that I also have to have the reference for the value and variable. Below is what I have now, but only want the output to be a line of text, not in a table or anything else. Thanks.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" 
                     value="{!contactList}" var="con" border="0" 
                     frame="none" id="table1">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputField value="{!con.CustomField__c}"
            rendered="{!con.CustomField__c != NULL}" 
        />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The field displays as expected; it shows the value for that field for that record. What I want to do is not use a table because the field is already in a larger table and a panel, so how can I declare those variables another way so the field just shows as a line of text?

I just want to show the

```html
<apex:outputField value="{!con.CustomField__c}" 
                  rendered="{!con.CustomField__c != NULL}" />`
```

without a table but where do the variables go?

Comment: Describe more clearly what you want to acheive. According to fragment of code You are showing the table with with custom field value for every contact record. If I understand correctly You want to display custom field value for single Contact record?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community; use [edit] to amend your post as per @gpoluch

Comment: You can use `apex:repeat` instead of `apex:pageBlockTable` to display only field values and style them as inline or inline-block if it meets your requirements